# Azure pipeline custom task - info logs are considered errors

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, nightwatch.js, nightwatch

I have developed an azure custom pipeline task (Build and Release) that executes nightwatch.js test cases.

nightwatch generates an INFO log while connecting to chrome (As Shown in the first image below). However, these logs are considered as errors in the pipleline and the custom task is shown as failure (refer 2nd image). Is there anyway I can supress INFO logs from nightwatch.js

[image: INFO log when nightwatch is executed]

[image: PipeLine error]

Task.json code

```
{
    "$schema": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-task-lib/master/tasks.schema.json",
    "id": "c786b1f1-37f1-44d6-ba55-5abe126bb031",
    "name": “CustomTaskName”,
    "friendlyName": "CustomTaskName Friendly Name,
    "description": “desc”,
    "helpMarkDown": "",
    "category": "Utility",
    "author": "Chandan",
    "version": {
        "Major": 0,
        "Minor": 1,
        "Patch": 0
    },
    "instanceNameFormat": "Echo $(url)",
    "inputs": [
        {
            "name": "url",
            "type": "string",
            "label": "URL of your website",
            "defaultValue": "",
            "required": true,
            "helpMarkDown": "URL of your website which needs testing"
        }
    ],
    "execution": {
        "PowerShell": {
            "target": "$(currentDirectory)\\command.ps1",
            "argumentFormat": "",
            "workingDirectory": ""
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you share your task code?

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk I have updated the task.json code in the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add `slient: true` to nightwatch.conf.js config file.

```
  live_output: false,
  silent: true,
  output: true,
  detailed_output: false,
  disable_error_log: false,
```

You can find relevant details available under Output Settings section of official [document](https://nightwatchjs.org/gettingstarted/configuration/).

[image]

Comment: I updated nightwatch.conf.js under test_settings. Still it didn't work

desiredCapabilities: {
        browserName : 'chrome',
        silent: true,
        live_output: false,
        output: true,
        detailed_output: false,
        disable_error_log: false
      }